# How to count number or rows in in one column, group by values in another column in Power BI

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have a table with two columns A, B.

```
Column A     Column B
Fruit        Apple
Fruit        Orange
Fruit        Pear
Veg          Beans
Veg          Potato
```

I need to count the number of occurrences of column B for each distinct value in Column A

```
Required Result:
Column A     Occurence
Fruit        3
Veg          2
```

Is there any function I can use in DAX to get the required result?

Comment: Have you tried any of `COUNT`, `DISTINCTCOUNT`, `COUNTROWS`, `COUNTX`?

Answer (score 0):

You can use these measure in dax:

Occurence = CALCULATE(CALCULATE(COUNT(Table1[ColumnA]));ALLEXCEPT(Table1;Table1[ColumnA]))

And use a table visualization in Power BI with Column A and other column with "Occurence" to see the result.